Incrementing TIMESTAMP column by INTERVAL produces Incorrect Datetime
I have MariaDB (10.5.18-MariaDB - MariaDB Server) set up on an Amazon Linux 2 system. The MariaDB timezone is set to SYSTEM, and the system timezone is Europe/London
I'm running the following queries
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`updated_at`) VALUES ('2021-03-27 1:30:00');

UPDATE test_table
   SET updated_at = updated_at + INTERVAL 1 YEAR

and receiving the following error
Incorrect datetime value: '2022-03-27 01:30:00' for column `test_table`.`updated_at` at row 1

I understand that the value quoted is not a real date in my DB due to Daylight Savings Time changes associated with the switch to British Summer Time
I was under the impression that TIMESTAMPs are stored as seconds from the epoch in UTC, and that updated_at + INTERVAL 1 YEAR would just add the number of seconds in a year to that value, thus always producing a valid result (within range)
It appears that some kind of conversion to DATETIME has occurred, however, is this correct?
If I'd like to keep the DB timezones, and column datatype, and I've always preferred the INTERVAL syntax. Is there a clean way to rewrite the UPDATE query to work as I expected?

Please add some where clause.
Use cast to change datetime string to datetime datatype

@ArtBindu There's only one row in the table, it's a test table that recreates the issue in a minimal format. I'm not sure what adding a where clause provides here

It appears that some kind of conversion to DATETIME has occurred, however, is this correct? Yes, all operations are performed in DATETIME. Execute SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:01' - INTERVAL 10 YEAR) + INTERVAL 10 YEAR and you'll receive correct output. If the server was working with timestamp values, the query would have failed due to the fact that the timestamp value calculated in parentheses is outside the acceptable values range.

@Akina Ah, ok, that makes sense with what I'm seeing, thanks

date math in mysql doesn't know anything about timezones and daylight saving.
timestamp columns are indeed stored as epoch times, but whenever you read or write to them, they are automatically converted to/from dateimes in the session timezone (which defaults to the database timezone, but is set on connection by some client libraries).
Together, this leads to problems like you are seeing.
Because of this IMO misfeature of timestamps, I strongly recommend using datetime column types and storing UTC times in them instead.
That said, you can safely do math on your timestamps by setting the session timezone first:
set session time_zone='+00:00';
update ...    


I think I was surprised that doing simple DateTime arithmetic had the potential to error like this. I may use DateTimes in UTC in the future, but I like the slimline efficiency of simple timestamps, and this is an edge case, so I'll use the workaround you provided for now. Thanks for the great answer!
